# How to run nuxt.js in real service?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, publishing, pm2, nuxt.js

I used vue-cli in

> vue init nuxt/express myProject

and,

> npm run dev

developed.

but,

> npm run build

after, was created dist file.

How i can run in real service in pm2?

(I will use ubuntu in AWS EC.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you just need to start your app like that:

```
pm2 start npm --name "your-project-name" -- start
```

Check the status:

```
pm2 status
```

and after you can restart / stop:

```
pm2 restart your-project-name
pm2 stop your-project-name
```

Comment: What is my project name?
`Nuxt / express`
Npm Do you need to target the folder created after run build?

Comment: The project name is just an alias for PM2. The most important is "pm2 start npm -- start", it's the way for PM2 to do a "npm run start", then the "start" script from nuxt know that the target folder is "dist".

Comment: I understand now. And I tried. **I finally solved it.** Thank you very much. Be happy.

Comment: Add, **What folders should be moved during the actual service?** `Build/main.js` and `.nuxt/dist`?

Answer (score 1):

Prerequisites

- node.js installed on web server
- nginx installed and configured on web server
- pm2 installed and configured on web server

Then

1. Add to your universal Nuxt app for serving it though PM2 is a file called **ecosystem.config.js.** Create a new file with that name in your root project directory and add the following content:

   ```
    module.exports = {
      apps: [
        {
          name: 'project-name',
          exec_mode: 'cluster',
          instances: 'max', // Or a number of instances
          script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',
          args: 'start'
        }
      ]
    }
   ```
2. Connect to your linux server via FTP (FileZilla or etc..)
   Send the blue files I marked to the server.
   (you don't need to upload node_modues, .nuxt, dist, .git, .idea, etc... folders)

   [image]
3. Connect server via ssh console, (windows : putty)
   and go to projects folder that you uploaded files.

   ```
    cd /
    cd var/www/project-name
   ```
4. Install node_modules folder by;

   ```
    npm install
   ```
5. Execute nuxt build and create .nuxt folder by;

   ```
    npm run build
   ```
6. Finally, ready to start starts pm2 server by;

   ```
    pm2 start
   ```